# How to fix "android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager" import error jetpack compose and MqttService.java

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, mqtt

How to fix the import error "android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager" in the MqttService.java class in jetpack compose I'm trying to work with mqtt and android but I have this error

Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Teste"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Teste">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.teste"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.teste"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    implementation("org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5")
    implementation("org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1")


    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")



}
```

error:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8058)                                                                                                        
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)                                                                                                        
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~JLox8OfsuMwxW3mCVxrEjg==/com.example.teste--Ik6OrSbSVdnTemMoaxLtg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~JLox8OfsuMwxW3mCVxrEjg==/com.example.teste--Ik6OrSbSVdnTemMoaxLtg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 93 more
```

class MQTT:

```
class MQTT {
    private var mqttClient: MqttAndroidClient?=null
    // TAG
    companion object {
        const val TAG = "AndroidMqttClient"
    }

    fun connect(context: Context) {
        val serverURI = "tcp://x.x.x.x:1883"
        mqttClient = MqttAndroidClient(context, serverURI, "go_mqtt_client")
        mqttClient?.setCallback(object : MqttCallback {
            override fun messageArrived(topic: String?, message: MqttMessage?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Receive message: ${message.toString()} from topic: $topic")
            }

            override fun connectionLost(cause: Throwable?) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connection lost ${cause.toString()}")
            }

            override fun deliveryComplete(token: IMqttDeliveryToken?) {

            }
        })
        val options = MqttConnectOptions()

        try {
            mqttClient?.connect(options, null, object : IMqttActionListener {
                override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection success")
                }

                override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failure")
                }
            })
        } catch (e: MqttException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }

    fun subscribe(topic: String, qos: Int = 1) {
        try {
            mqttClient?.subscribe(topic, qos, null, object : IMqttActionListener {
                override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Subscribed to $topic")
                }

                override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to subscribe $topic")
                }
            })
        } catch (e: MqttException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }


    fun unsubscribe(topic: String) {
        try {
            mqttClient?.unsubscribe(topic, null, object : IMqttActionListener {
                override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unsubscribed to $topic")
                }

                override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to unsubscribe $topic")
                }
            })
        } catch (e: MqttException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun publish(topic: String, msg: String, qos: Int = 1, retained: Boolean = false) {
        try {
            val message = MqttMessage()
            message.payload = msg.toByteArray()
            message.qos = qos
            message.isRetained = retained
            mqttClient?.publish(topic, message, null, object : IMqttActionListener {
                override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "$msg published to $topic")
                }

                override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to publish $msg to $topic")
                }
            })
        } catch (e: MqttException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun disconnect() {
        try {
            mqttClient?.disconnect(null, object : IMqttActionListener {
                override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected")
                }

                override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken?, exception: Throwable?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to disconnect")
                }
            })
        } catch (e: MqttException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

}
```

class MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val mqtt = MQTT()
        setContent {
            TesteTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    mqtt.connect(LocalContext.current)
                    mqtt.subscribe("topic/test")
                }
            }
        }
        mqtt.publish("topic/test","Testar")
        mqtt.disconnect()
    }
}
```

Server mqtt go:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    mqtt "github.com/mochi-mqtt/server/v2"
    "github.com/mochi-mqtt/server/v2/hooks/auth"
    "github.com/mochi-mqtt/server/v2/listeners"
)

func main() {
    // Create signals channel to run server until interrupted
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        <-sigs
        done <- true
    }()

    opts := mqtt.Options{
        InlineClient: true,
    }
    // Create the new MQTT Server.
    server := mqtt.New(&opts)

    // Allow all connections.
    _ = server.AddHook(new(auth.AllowHook), nil)

    // Create a TCP listener on a standard port.
    tcp := listeners.NewTCP("t1", "0.0.0.0:1883", nil)
    err := server.AddListener(tcp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go func() {
        err := server.Serve()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for range time.Tick(time.Second * 5) {
            err := server.Publish("topic/test", []byte("Hello World!\n"), false, 0)
            if err != nil {
                server.Log.Error("server.Publish", "error", err)
            }
            server.Log.Info("main.go issued direct message to direct/publish")
        }
    }()

    // Run server until interrupted
    <-done

    // Cleanup
}
```

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/android-connects-mqtt-using-kotlin):

Does anyone have any idea what it is?

Comment: You haven't included the actual error in the question and the manifest is not useful here, the `build.gradle` is likely to be more useful

Comment: You have still not actually included the error, all you have is the name of a class

Comment: I included the error

Comment: You've now included a section out of the middle of the error. You really are trying hard to make this hard for us to help here.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want me to publish the entire error? thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really have lost interest in helping here, if you are not prepared to share all the relevant information, I can't be bothered to help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I added more information to my question thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.testar"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.testar"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    implementation("org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.5")
}
```

Main class:

```
package com.example.testar

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import com.example.testar.ui.theme.TestarTheme
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence
import java.nio.charset.Charset

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
   
    private val mqttServerUri = "tcp://x.x.x.x:1883"
    private val mqttTopic = "topic/test"
    private lateinit var mqttClient: MqttClient
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestarTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val messageState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                    MqttSubscriptionApp(messageState)                        
                    startMqttSubscription(messageState)
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private fun startMqttSubscription(messageState: MutableState<String>) {
        try {
            mqttClient = MqttClient(mqttServerUri, MqttClient.generateClientId(), MemoryPersistence())
            val options = MqttConnectOptions()
            options.isAutomaticReconnect = true
            options.isCleanSession = false
            mqttClient.connect(options)

            mqttClient.setCallback(object : MqttCallback {
                override fun connectionLost(cause: Throwable?) {
                    
                }

                override fun messageArrived(topic: String?, message: MqttMessage?) {
                    
                    val receivedMessage = message?.toString()
                    if (!receivedMessage.isNullOrEmpty()) {                            
                        val utf8String = receivedMessage.toByteArray(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))                            
                        val convertedString = String(utf8String, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))                            
                        messageState.value = convertedString
                    }
                }

                override fun deliveryComplete(token: IMqttDeliveryToken?) {
                 
                }
            })

            mqttClient.subscribe(mqttTopic, 0)
            val topic: MqttTopic = mqttClient.getTopic(mqttTopic)
            val publication = "Hello world 10"
            val message = MqttMessage(publication.toByteArray())
            val token:MqttDeliveryToken = topic.publish(message)

        } catch (e: MqttException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MqttSubscriptionApp(messageState: MutableState<String>) {
    Column {
        TopAppBar(title = { Text(text = "MQTT message") })
        Surface {
            Column {
                Text(text = "MESSSAGE:")
                Text(text = messageState.value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```